# How do I handle HTML5 Multiple File uploads in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, html, file-upload

I found the [following great thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery/8758614#8758614) with an explanation of how to do file uploads through AJAX/Jquery using the new HTML5 FormData API

Here's a slightly updated version of that code, with the newer JQuery 1.8+ syntax

```
$(':button').click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Upload',  //my ASP.NET MVC method
        type: 'POST',
        // handle the progress report
        xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction,    false); // For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },

        // Form data
        data: formData,

        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    })
    .done(function(){
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert("error");
    });
});

function progressHandlingFunction(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
    }
}
```

and here's the form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
<progress></progress>
```

On the server side, we have something like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // do something with file
    return "you uploaded a file called " + file.FileName;
}
```

This works great. UNTIL you decide to use the "multiple" attribute on the file dialog, and send multiple files.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
<progress></progress>
```

You'll find various pages online suggesting the following solutions

```
public string Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    foreach(var file in files)
         ...
}
```

Oops. Doesn't work

```
public string Upload(List<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    foreach(var file in files)
         ...
}
```

Nope. Doesn't work.

```
public string Upload(IEnumerable files)
{
    foreach(var file in files)
         ...
}
```

Doesn't even *compile*

```
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
    foreach(HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
         ...
}
```

Guess what? Doesn't work. Lets try dealing with Request.Files instead. Good old reliable Request.Files. Never fails.

```
public string Upload()
{
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase uf in Request.Files)
         ...
}
```

Spoiler alert: It Doesn't work.

Aha. Got it! I'll iterate over the keys in Request.Files instead.

```
public string Upload()
{
    foreach(var key in Request.Files.AllKeys)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[key];
    }
}
```

Yet again, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What *does* work, is the following, [from the blog](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/06/Using-the-HTML5-input-typefile-multiplemultiple-Tag-in-ASPNET) of the always dependable and dynamically haired Rick Strahl

```
public string Upload()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[i];
    } 
}
```

The reason behind this is that the collection of files passed to `Request.Files` **all have the same name**, because they come from a singular file upload dialog.

the server side method is passed a *single* object containing the files, and for some reason Request.Files is the only way to get at it.

Hopefully I've saved someone a bit of headache by adding this in.

Comment: What about the file types? I want to allow user to upload files of type `".jpg" , ".gif", ".png"` ... but since all the files will have same name then how could I get the type of any file?

Comment: You still have access to the filename, but all the *post variables* containing those files have the same name. Once you have assigned your file to the `file` variable you can check the name and extension, and filter on that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case what worked for me was binding all my files to a ViewModel field. ViewModel would be the model the I use for my front end.

```
@using School.ViewModels
@model UserProfileViewModel


<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="username"name="username" type="text" />
<input name="Myfiles" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

UserProfileViewModel.cs

```
namespace School.ViewModels
{
    public class UserProfileViewModel
    {
        public long Username { get; set; }

        public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Myfiles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UserProfilePicturesController.cs

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Username,Myfilese")] UserprofileViewModel userprofileViewModel)
{
     var files = userprofileViewModel.Myfiles;
     foreach(HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
     {
         //do something here
     }
}
```