# Multiple files upload in onedrive (skydrive)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, onedrive

It is possible to upload multiple files in onedrive(skydrive) using WL.upload ? I tried something but I always get an error like "element must be an html input element" or something like this. I use onedrive sdk 5.6 and the application is build in ASP.NET MVC 5. The problem is that I created an input of type="file" with the attribute multiple set so I can select multiple files from my computer but the upload method from WL api ask for an element property that is actual an id to an input element of type="file". Because my input is set on multiple I tried to iterate through the files that contains and to create an input element to pass to the method, but it's doesn't work because due to security reasons I can set a value of an input element.

So, does anybody knows how I can do this ? Thanks

This is what I have tried:

```
 <div id="save-to-skydrive-dialog-content-multiple">
        <p>select a file</p>
        <form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>
            <input id="save-to-skydrive-file-input-multiple" type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
        </form>
        <p>upload file</p>
        <button id="save-to-skydrive-upload-multiple-button">upload multiple</button>
 </div>

function saveMultipleToSkyDrive() {
        WL.fileDialog({
            mode: 'save'
        }).then(function (response) {
            var folder = response.data.folders[0];

            var elements = document.getElementById("save-to-skydrive-file-input-multiple").files;

            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

                var htmlInPutElement = document.createElement('input');
                htmlInPutElement.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                htmlInPutElement.value = elements.item(i);

                WL.api({

                })

                WL.upload({
                    path: folder.id,
                    element: htmlInPutElement,
                    overwrite: 'rename'
                }).then(function (response) {
                    log("You save to" + response.source + ". " + "Below is the result of the upload");
                    log("");
                    log(JSON.stringify(response));
                },
                    function (errorResponse) {
                        log("WL.upload errorResponse = " + JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
                    },
                    function (progress) {
                    });
            }
        }, function (errorResponse) {
            log("WL.upload errorResponse = " + JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
        }
        );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember of messing with the `input[file]` element, you can't set the value of an `input[file]` like that, for security reasons.

```
            var htmlInPutElement = document.createElement('input');
            htmlInPutElement.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            htmlInPutElement.value = elements.item(i);
```

A solution would be to post the files to an interim `action` on your `controller`, and then do the OneDrive API stuff in that `action` method instead.  You can iterate through `Request.Files` (although it can be tricky with the multiple property, I learned the hard way - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784647/how-do-i-handle-html5-multiple-file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc/21784648#21784648) for more info

Comment: I know that because of security reasons I can't set a value of an input[file] and also I thought to make the logic in controller but the problem is that I want to do all the stuff in javascript, I don't want to work with any action method from controller.

Comment: well, that's the only way I know how to do it. the only other way would be to have separate file inputs to start with and not use a multiple attribute

Comment: thanks for your answer. I also think there maybe it could be a way to send a parameter to method from the api that Microsoft offer. until now I find only the method with an input[file] (I just started to learn OneDrive sdk).

Comment: I found a way to do this, after a little search work. Unfortunatelly, I couldn't find a way to upload multiple files from javascript, only from c# code. I post here the solution, maybe it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer, but not in javascript, in c# code.

Html input:

```
 <p>Upload Files</p>
<div id="save-to-skydrive-dialog-content">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "Auth", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" name="file" multiple />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
    }
</div>
```

C# method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFiles()
    {
        var files = Request.Files;

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            LiveLoginResult loginStatus = await authClient.InitializeWebSessionAsync(HttpContext);
            if (loginStatus.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                connectedClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.authClient.Session);
                LiveOperationResult result = await connectedClient.GetAsync("me/skydrive");
                string folderId = (string)result.Result["id"];

                for (var i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    var fileName = Request.Files[i].FileName;
                    var fileStream = Request.Files[i].InputStream;

                    LiveOperationResult uploadResult = await connectedClient.UploadAsync(folderId, fileName, fileStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
                }
            }
        }
        return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
    }
```

Comment: you welcome! in the future maybe I will find a way in javascript only!